# Refresh text input on jQuery Mobile (themes)

Tags: jquery, mobile, input, jquery-mobile, refresh

I'd like to refresh in an input text after dynamically add the attribute "data-theme".

How can I do this?

I'd like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Sgrve/5/

If I click the "Change Theme", I want to change the color of the input.

Data-theme attribute change but the color don't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Sgrve/3/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Sgrve/14/ (From your comment)
- http://jsfiddle.net/Sgrve/20/ (Select theme from radio group)

JS

```
$('#addContent').append('<input type="text" value="Default Value" id="newContent" />');
alert('Adding Dynamic content/element');

$('#newContent').val('Hello new Value 123');
alert('Changing the value');

$('#home').trigger('create');
alert('Refreshing JQM controls and look');
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="addContent">
            <!-- Add Dynamic content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE From your comment

JS

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $('#txtContent').attr('data-theme','e').removeClass('ui-body-d').addClass('ui-body-e').trigger('create');
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
    alert("Theme = " + $('#txtContent').attr('data-theme'));
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="addContent">
            <p><input type="text" value="I want to copy you" data-theme="d" id="txtContent" /></p>
            <p><input type="text" value="Try to look like me" data-theme="e" id="txtContent2" /></p>
            <p><button id="btn1">Change theme</button></p>
            <p><button id="btn2">View theme</button></p>
            <!-- Add Dynamic content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Sgrve/5/ // If I click the "Change Theme", I want to change the color of the input

Comment: Updated answer based from your comment

Answer (score -1):

Try running

```
$('#page_id').page('refresh');
```

or

```
$('#list_id').listview('refresh');
```

if it's inside a List.

Comment: Not work. On chrome console: Uncaught no such method 'refresh' for page widget instance